# ChromeOS App: Simple example app which opens/saves to Google Drive as well as Download and External Drive

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api, google-chrome-os

I've succeeded in using the filesystem API in a Chrome App on my Chromebook.  But none of the examples I've found allow you to open files from Google Drive.  Any number of apps on the Chromebook (supplied or added) open the exact same dialog but with Google Drive showing on the left along with Download and External Drive.

Is there a simple example App which shows how this is done?

Or am I simply missing some concept which will make even the Diff or TextEdit examples work this way if done (like pushing the App to the store, perhaps -- right now I'm just loading and packing my own off local storage)?

Comment: You can access google drive files by using its API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Comment: Thanks.  But this is the low-level API.  I'm looking for example code which uses a standard dialog (Google Docs and some other apps I've downloaded use the exact same one) for Chrome OS which includes filesystem and Google Drive files.  I suspect it's just the filesystem API open file dialog with some manifest.json magic, or that that dialog automatically includes Google Drive info when you download via Google Play.  Does anyone know or have sample code?

Answer (score 0):

From reading your comment it seems that you will want to use google drive sdk in order to integrate the '[open file](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open)' dialog into your web app.

and even more to the point - the [file 'picker'](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) - In order to integrate the file picker you will need to use google JS client lib. Then you will be able to open the file dialog with a code like this:

```
// Use the Google Loader script to load the google.picker script.
google.setOnLoadCallback(createPicker);
google.load('picker', '1');

// Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
function createPicker() {
    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
        addView(google.picker.ViewId.IMAGE_SEARCH).
        setCallback(pickerCallback).
        build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Ido, I appreciate your help. This looks promising, but won't work under an app (manifest.json with an app tag). The code has document.write() calls, which are
forbidden in the app model. (Hmm. Not sure the extensions I've been looking at follow the app model.)
Example: 'https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/530/?mui=ca#co' is gmail offline. It does what I'm talking about
when you click compose and then the paperclip. (The resulting dialog
is completely different on Linux vs Chromebook, which implies it's from the browser.) The string 'picker' does not seem to be anywhere in the code.

Comment: Drat.  Just uploaded it to the Chrome Store as a test, and was not too surprised to see that downloading it from the App Store doesn't give it the ability to see Google Drive items in the standard ChromeOS file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to use the <input type="file" name="somename" size="chars"> code in the browser.  That is what is producing this.  It creates a standard way to read in the file from disk or Google drive.  It's what I've seen in multiple apps.  All the API stuff is a red herring, if what one wants is to get access to this simple dialog.

However, it doesn't allow me to WRITE, just to read, since one would expect it to be returning only the content of the file, not a file handle of any sort, or even the full name.  I'll play with it and figure out whether there's any hook I can find to tell me to write it to Google drive (using the links Ido provided above).  If anyone has suggestions on where to snag the full path (or an interesting Google Drive path) somewhere using this, I'll love to hear them.